# d3 visualization not appearing

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to get a very basic d3 visualization working, but all I get is a blank browser window.

Here's my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
    <title>My Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `code.js`:

```
console.log("test");

d3.select("body").append("h1").html("Here are some words")
```

My console prints `test`. But nothing appears in the browser window. When I `inspect element`, nothing has been added.

I've tried loading the localhost page via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` and via `npm install -g http-server` plus `http-server &`.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Did you check your network section in browser if your d3 js file is loading?

Comment: @AbhayDixit The network tab says it's loading, code 200.

Comment: What happens if you do the `d3` command in your console?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters I get an object with a bunch of keys: active, arc, area, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change your HTML code for the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>    
    <title>My Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="container"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I just put the line which reference the "code.js" inside the **body** tags

Comment: That works. Weird, I've never had to do that before in order to get d3 to work. My other projects have used Rails and Angular, but this project is pure JS. Why does it work fine in @MaximilianPeters 's JSFiddle?

Comment: While I know why your answer works, the OP does not. Perhaps you should explain why your answer works so other future visitors are not mystified too.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'd be happy to have you explain it as well!

Comment: @RobertLongson Since he doesn't seem to be responding would you mind telling me? I don't really care who tells me as long as someone does.

Comment: I agree with @RobertLongson, I should explain the answer more than just indicate the solution to the problem. The previous code does not work because the code that manipulates the "d3.select" function needs to be inside the body of the HTML code. If it was just a style definition (CSS) there would be no drawbacks, but references to D3 need to be inside the body. At least I have been doing this in my projects and it has worked correctly. I hope the clarification is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @federicomedrano! But, why do my Angular and Rails projects still work without doing that?

Comment: I really do not know. I work with pure D3, HTML and CSS, and incorporating the solutions into C# projects, I do not know why your other projects can work without the change I've suggested. As I mentioned, I work that way and so far I have not had problems, the examples and documentation that I have reviewed always do it that way.

Comment: OK, since nobody knows the code is parsed from top to bottom so if you put it in the head it runs before the body has loaded, if you put it at the end it runs after the content exists so it can then select the other body code.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson!